# How do you run mono from the terminal in OS X?

Tags: macos, mono

I'm a Microsoft stack developer with very little experience with Unix/Linux. I'm trying to run a .NET executable using mono from the terminal in OS X. Either something is incorrectly installed or I'm just fundamentally misunderstanding things in this environment.

[image: Evidence of me clearly not knowing what I'm doing]

Any advice?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Specify the path. Try

```
./mono
```

rather than just

```
mono
```

Despite being in the same folder as `mono`, linux and unix don't automatically look in the current folder for executables and other files.